# Time complexity of Insertion Sort of an array of n numbers, with additional information

Tags: time-complexity, insertion-sort

Let there be an array A of n numbers.
Let's define an inversion: there are two indexes, i < j, such that A[i] > A[j].
If my array A has K inversions, what is the time complexity of sorting the array with insertion sort?

I understand that the less inversions we have, the closer our array is to its sorted array. If there was just one inversion, that means there are only 2 elements which are not sorted (if there was more, then we'd have more inversions). However, I'm not sure how to analyze the general case.
I'd appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0):

The insertion code provided below also remarks its number of operations, the calculation is for the worst case in which the array A is completely opposite of the sort. All elements of array A need to be swapped in every case.

```
for ( i = 1 ; i < n ; i++ )                     // 1(initialization) + n(check)
{
     j = i;                                     // n-1(initialization)
     while ( ( j > 0 ) && ( A[j-1] > A[j] ) )   // 2(∑ᵢ₌₁^{n} i) - 1 (checks)
     {
          temp = A[j];                          // ∑ᵢ₌₁^{n-1} i (operation)
          A[j] = A[j-1];                        // ∑ᵢ₌₁^{n-1} i (operation)
          A[j-1] = temp;                        // ∑ᵢ₌₁^{n-1} i (operation)
          j = j – 1;                            // ∑ᵢ₌₁^{n-1} i (operation)
     }
}                                               // n-1(incrementation)
```

Noticed that ∑ᵢ₌₁^{n} i means the sum of the n natural numbers starting from 1.

∑ᵢ₌₁^{n} i = n(n+1)/2

> Number of Operations (worst case)
>
> = 1 + n + (n-1) + 2(n(n+1)/2) - 1 + 4(n(n-1)/2) + (n-1)
>
> = 2n + n(n+1) - 1 + 2(n^2 - n) + n - 1
>
> = 2n + n^2 + n - 1 + 2n^2 + n -1
>
> = 3n^2 + 2n - 2

The number of operations for the worst case is f(n) = 3n^2 + 2n - 2. Generally, we consider of best case (array perfectly sorted), worst case, and average case ((worst + best) / 2).

Another way to analyze the complexity of the algorithm is asymptotic notation. In this case, the upper bound of f(n) = O(n^2).